# Clone MySQL database when had read-only permission

Tags: mysql, database, clone

I have `database1` (~500MB), which can be access in a read-only mode by `user1`.
I have empty database `database2`, with full privilege by `user2`.

Now, I want to clone `database1` into `database2`.

I have tried `mysqldump`, but it says `access denied`.

Any better way? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, mysqldump tries to lock all tables before dumping them - in order to create a consistent snapshot. I assume that `user1` does not have the privilege to do that.

You can use either `--single-transaction` or `--skip-lock-tables` on the command line. The first option uses a single transaction for the whole operation. This works perfectly if all tables are transactional and the database is small. If the database is huge, this can have serious effects on other applications.

If in doubt, try `--skip-lock-tables` first. However, the dump may be inconsistent, if other applications make changes during the dump.

Complete example to clone database:

```bsh
mysqldump -h host1 -u user1 -ppass1 --single-transaction database1 |
mysql -h host2 -u user2 -ppass2 database2
```